# how do I remove parts of the Kendo UI Scheduler that I don't want to show?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'd like remove the header controls from the top of the Kendo UI Scheduler control, i.e. the part outlined in red from this screenshot:

[image]

I just want to show one static Day view for a single day. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 8):

for all Day Slot hide

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    allDaySlot: false,
});
```

for Toolbar hide:

```
<style>
    .k-scheduler-toolbar {
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You also need padding set to 0 for toolbar

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to remove all of that, but you can at least remove the All Day slot by selecting allDaySlot: false in the views collection.  If you only want to show the "day" view, you would use something like this (also showing how to remove footer; same doesn't appear to work for header, though):

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    views: [ 
    { type: "day", selected: true, allDaySlot: false}
    ],
    footer: false // removes the footer
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the information below:

1. To remove the footer you can set the [`footer`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-footer) option to false
2. The toolbar can be removed using CSS styles:

   `.k-scheduler-toolbar {
       display: none;
   }`
3. All-day slot can be removed using the [`allDaySlot`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-allDaySlot)